# use of \newcommand in user-written LaTeX package

Tags: macros, packages

I've tried to put into a package a LaTeX macro I use all the time in my Beamer slide.
Here it is

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{icone}[2018/06/20 insert journal icone in beamer slides]
\RequirePackage[absolute,showboxes,overlay]{textpos}

\newcommand{\icone}[1]{%
\begin{textblock*}{15mm}[0,0](315pt,5pt)%
\includegraphics[height=20mm,keepaspectratio]{/path/to/predefined/folder/{#1}}%
\end{textblock*}}
```

This command perfectly works when I use it directly in my file.
But my package does not work. The error message is

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \def
```

What I've read is it could be preferable to use `\def`instead of `\newcommand`in a .sty file. I tried but it doesn't work either.

**Addendum**

Actually, I'm not able to explain why, but I definitely need to add `{}` to the argument of my own macro. 
I tested with and without (again a macro inside a package) and I needed them.
For instance the following works

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{citation}[2018/06/20 insert citation at bottom right of beamer slides]
\RequirePackage[absolute,showboxes,overlay]{textpos}
\newcommand{\citationfoot}[2]{%
\begin{textblock*}{55mm}[0,0](250pt, 250pt)%
{\setlength{\baselineskip}{.6\baselineskip}%
\rule{30mm}{.25mm} \\%
\tiny%
\textit{{#1} \\ {#2}}%
\par}%
\end{textblock*}%
}
```

while this one doesn't

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{citation}[2018/06/20 insert citation at bottom right of beamer slides]
\RequirePackage[absolute,showboxes,overlay]{textpos}
\newcommand{\citationfoot}[2]{%
\begin{textblock*}{55mm}[0,0](250pt, 250pt)%
{\setlength{\baselineskip}{.6\baselineskip}%
\rule{30mm}{.25mm} \\%
\tiny%
\textit{#1 \\ #2}%
\par}%
\end{textblock*}%
}
```

Comment: I experience no problems with placing the definition of `\icone` in an external .sty file if I change `\includegraphics[height=20mm,keepaspectratio{/path/to/predefined/folder/{#1}}` to `\includegraphics[height=20mm,keepaspectratio]{/path/to/predefined/folder/#1}`. Can you spot the differences?

Comment: actually I added the braces `{}` because it did not work without in the package (I didn't need them in the preamble of course). And I corrected my first shot as the lack of `[`was a copy-paste issue...